# Text element as a pseudo-link

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, hyperlink

I'm building an interactive table with html/css/jquery and want to use the slide-toggle jQuery action on when clicking my text elements. I have found that I cannot use an "a" tag, as an empty href="" will just reload the page and omitting the "href" altogether turns my cursor into a "I" when hovering over the element, just as it would with a "p" tag.

Basically what I am asking is, is there a way to add a text element that makes the cursor act as a link when hovered over(mouse head turns into hand with pointing finger), but does not link to anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of turning the cursor into a pointer which you can easily do using CSS `cursor` property with a value of `pointer` use [`event.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) which will prevent the issue which you are facing.

```
$('div.toggle').hide();
  $('a.open_toggle').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle(500);
  }             
);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yK56/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this CSS to get the mouse cursor behavior you are lookign for:

```
.link {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then add this class to your HTML like this:

```
<span class='link'>link</span>
```

Or you can add it to clickable elements like this ([css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/give-clickable-elements-a-pointer-cursor/)):

```
a[href], input[type='submit'], input[type='image'], label[for], select, button, .pointer {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can style the cursor with CSS like this:

```
p:hover{cursor:pointer}
```

Also you can prevent an anchor link to execute a page reload like this (jQuery):

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// do something...
})
```

Comment: I was completely unaware that the cursor was manipulable, this is a great solution, thank you!